# Where to write the "section-document" in Excel using power query?

Tags: powerquery

I can write "expression-document" in advance editor.
But putting the "section-document" will cause error.

According to [PDF](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&oq=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.1077j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)`Power Query for Excel Formula Language Specification, Aug 2015`, `Page 15, 2.1 Documents`

> A document either consists of exactly one expression or of groups of
>   definitions organized into sections.

When I put "section definition" like following, in "Advance Editor", the error message is "Invalid Expression":

```
section SectionA;
A = 1;
```

It is quite obviously that the Advance Editor expecting "expression-document", not "section-document".  (These 2 terms come from [PDF](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&oq=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.1077j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) page 107, 12.2.1 Document.  And "expression-document" is just an "expression", 12.2.3.1 Expressions)

I sense that "Section" in PQ would be a feature to organize code as some way like "Module".  I would like to use it.

However, I find no way to code "section-document". (`page 98, 11.Sections` of the spec)

A work-a-round is to create a "Query" named as said, MyFunSet, which returns a record of many functions.

```
Query-Name: MyFunSet has following "expression" in Adv Editor

[ FunA = () => ...,
   FunB = (x) => ...
]
```

When using this `MyFunSet` in other "Query" would be like following.  I have tested that it works.

```
  let a = MyFunSet[FunA]()
  ,   b = MyFunSet[FunB](1)
  in  1
```

or

```
let FunA = MyFunSet[FunA]
,   FunB = MyFunSet[FunB]
,   a = FunA()
,   b = FunB(1)
in  1
```

This work-a-round is OK, but not nice.

**Finding#1 (#settions)**
[PDF](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&oq=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.1077j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) page 100, PQ expression `#sections` will return a record of sections.  Create a new query of value #sections, the record returned has ONE field of name 'Section1' and value is a record of all queries in the Excel workbook.  Eg,
A workbook has

```
Query1 = ...
Query2 = ...
Query3 = #sections
```

Query3 will return a record like this:

```
[ Section1 = [Query1 = ..., Query2 = ..., Query3 = ...] ]
```

According to this, I interpret that whole Excel workbook only allow one section and the name is "Section1"

**Finding#2 (section-access expression)** [PDF](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&oq=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.1077j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) page 110,

```
12.2.3.13 Section-access expression
   section-access-expression: identifier ! identifier
```

**Finding#3 (Document)** [PDF](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&oq=Power%20Query%20for%20Excel%20Formula%20Language%20Specification&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.1077j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) page 107,

```
12.2.1 Documents
    document: 
        section-document
        expression-document
```

"Advanced Editor" accepts only expression-document, not section-document

**Finding#4 (Export the PQ as *.odc)**

In Excel 356, each `loaded` PQ is a workbook connection and can exported as *.odc

- Locate the cell within the `loaded` query table,
- go menu "Data", click "Connection Properties..",
- in page tab, "Definiton", click the "Export Connection File",
- a *.odc is created.
- examine the  tag in the *.odc file

following is find

```
<Formula><![CDATA[let
Query3 = #sections,
in
Query3]]></Formula>
```

These 4 findings make me feel that one workbook will always create only one "section" of name "section1".  If an workbook can "refer" to one or more other workbook, multiple-section is allowed.  These comes with 2 questions:

- How to refer?
- How to rename the section-name which is always "Section1" to other name?

I would like to know how to use -- "section" in Excel Power Query.

Comment: what error occurring

Comment: Invalid expression.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. You can't edit the section document directly.
In Excel/Power Query each time you edit the expression of some Query you're writing a part of the section document.

If you define "Query1" as `1 + 1` and create a separate "Query2" as `Query1 + 1`, then Excel writes out this section document:

```
section Section1;

shared Query1 = 1 + 1;

shared Query2 = Query1 + 1;
```

Your workaround should also work fine. I think that's what e.g. this ["M" library on GitHub](https://github.com/tycho01/pquery) does.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify - the "section" keyword is automatically added internally by excel.

When you write queries that are displayed as a separate queries excel saves the m language query code in just one "М document" - the file where those queries are separated into sections. 
This file containing all M code is base64 encoded and added to excel workbook zip archive.